# Incorrect CRC8 checksum computation

Tags: c#, checksum, crc

I got this class to compute the CRC8 checksum of a byte[]:

```
public static class Crc8
    {
        static byte[] table = new byte[256];
        // x8 + x7 + x6 + x4 + x2 + 1
        const byte poly = 0xd5;

        public static byte ComputeChecksum(params byte[] bytes)
        {
            byte crc = 0;
            if (bytes != null && bytes.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (byte b in bytes)
                {
                    crc = table[crc ^ b];
                }
            }
            return crc;
        }

        static Crc8()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
            {
                int temp = i;
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
                {
                    if ((temp & 0x80) != 0)
                    {
                        temp = (temp << 1) ^ poly;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp <<= 1;
                    }
                }
                table[i] = (byte)temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

And in the Main I got:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string number = "123456789";



    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToByte(Crc8.ComputeChecksum(StringToByteArray(number))).ToString("x2"));

    Console.ReadLine();

}

private static byte[] StringToByteArray(string str)
{
    ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
    return enc.GetBytes(str);
}
```

This results in 0xBC

However, according to: http://www.scadacore.com/field-tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/
this is incorrect, because the checksum for the CheckSum8 Xor is 0x31.

What did I wrong there?

Answer (score 2):

On the linked site only some 16 and 32 bit CRCs are listed, the 
CheckSum8Xor is **not** a CRC. The **0xBC** comes from a 8-bit CRC
called "CRC-8/DVB-S2", see http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/1-15.htm

Comment: Thanks, I've posted my own answer, if someone has interest of it.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, ok, so I've overiterpreted this checksum computation.

Well, in that case, it's easy:

```
public static byte Checksum8XOR(byte[] data)
        {
            byte checksum = 0x00;

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {

                checksum ^= data[i];

            }


            return checksum;
        }
```